# How cover a ControllerAdvice dedicated to handle exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, junit

I am having problems testing my HandleException, even though I have searched I only find solutions for a standard controller that integrates error management but I have it separately.

The problem is that when it comes to doing the unit tests and its coverage, I don't know how to cover it properly.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AmazonClientException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAmazonClientException(AmazonClientException ex) {
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AmazonS3Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAmazonS3Exception(AmazonS3Exception ex) {
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ex));

    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
    }

}

RestExceptionHandler.class
```

ApiError.class

```
@Data
public class ApiError {

    private HttpStatus status;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private String message;
    private String debugMessage;

    private ApiError() {
        setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    ApiError(HttpStatus status) {
        this();
        setStatus(status);
    }

    ApiError(HttpStatus status, Throwable ex) {
        this();
        setStatus(status);
        setMessage("Unexpected error");
        setDebugMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, Throwable ex) {
        this();
        setStatus(status);
        setMessage(message);
        setDebugMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
 }
```

How can see, i only use my RestExceptionHandler for that, not call another Business class.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unit test `@ControllerAdvice` annotated classes, you can use something called `MockMvc` which Spring provides.
It is a very elegant way of unit testing your controllers and subsequent controller advices.

So, let's say this is my controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class RobotController {

    private RobotService robotService;

    @GetMapping
    public Collection<Integer> get() {
        throw new DemoException();
    }
}
```

And here's my controller advice; `DemoException` is just an empty class that extends `RuntimeException`.

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(DemoException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(DemoException dex) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(400)
                .body("Bad request");
    }
}
```

So, this means, sending a GET request to `BASEURL/api` will give me `Bad request` text response with 400 status code.

Okay, since we are done with the setup, let's move to the actual unit test. This is a very simple unit test, but it does what you need.

```java
public class AdviceTest {

    private final MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(new RobotController())
            .setControllerAdvice(new RestExceptionHandler())
            .build();

    @Test
    void testGetFails() {
        mockMvc.perform(
                    MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api")
                ).andExpect(
                       status().isBadRequest()
                );
    }
}
```

So, let me explain the initialization of the `MockMvc` object. There are two versions.

1. **Standalone setup** in which you just provide manually created controller objects.
2. **Web application context** in which you just provide an autowired application context.

You can also autowire `MockMvc` object.

Out of those 2, I really like the former, because it does not include the whole Spring context, hence it is faster.

There are a lot of methods available from checking the json content to paths. You can read more here:

[Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

[Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring)

Comment: Oh, its too simple, thanks, always see people who have the controller advice for handle and RestApi. Thanks for your help.